# Trying to build MariaDB, I get the error: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

Tags: apt, server, 20.04

I follow [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/get-involved/getting-started-for-developers/get-code-build-test/) docs on how to build MariaDB on my Ubuntu.

It says run

```
On a Debian based distribution:
apt-get build-dep mariadb-server-10.X
where X is the suffix of the major version.
```

So I run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mariadb-server-10.5
```

and get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list
```

This error hint message is meaningless to me.

---

Even tried

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mariadb-server-10.5
sudo apt build-dep mariadb-server-10.5
sudo apt build-dep mariadb-server-10.4
sudo apt build-dep mariadb-server-10.3
```

Also, used a simpler command and yet I get the same problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list
```

How to fix this error?

My Ubuntu is a server with a gui desktop installed on top of it

```
$ uname -a
Linux myserver 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PS. While I probably can use `apt install`, I do not really want to install anything more than it is mandated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of your APT repositories is here: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

In this file, there will be some lines that says:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
```

*(Note: You may have a prefix in front of "archive" - for instance, since I'm in Denmark, for me it's dk.archive.ubuntu.com)*

Since MariaDB is part of the "Universe" packages (this can be checked on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)) and you want to bulid from the source files, you have to edit the file with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment the deb-src lines, like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
```

I imagine this should do the trick.